# Can you play three skips then a reverse?

Tags: uno

In a two-player Uno game, can the same person play 3 skips and immediately continue with a reverse of the same colour?

Comment: Please use titles that match just your specific question and not every question on the site.

Comment: Not only CAN you, but using multiple skips/reverses to change colors is a core strategy of two player Uno!

Answer (score 12):

Yes, in a 2 player game, playing a skip would make it your turn again, so you could play another skip if you have one.

Playing a reverse will also skip your opponent’s turn, only in a 2 player game.

From [the rules](https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/42001pr.pdf):

> **Rules for Two Players** - The following special rules apply to two-player UNO:
>
> > 1. Playing a Reverse card works like playing a Skip card. By playing the Reverse card, you may immediately play another card.
> > 2. By playing a Skip card, you may immediately play another card.